# How to setup nested grid with Skeleton

Tags: skeleton-css-boilerplate

I want to add a grid of images and content in the main content area of my website page.
I have a basic two column template, and I want to place the grid in the large content area. Everything works fine, but as soon as I resize to portrait I loose all my margins between divs. I am not too sure what is the proper way to group these items in skeleton. Do i need to end my container for each row? Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="four columns"></div>
    <div class="twelve columns">

        <!-- grid goes here -->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="six columns alpha"></div>
        <div class="six columns omega"></div>
        <div class="six columns alpha"></div>
        <div class="six columns omega"></div>
        </div>


    </div><!-- end twelve columns>
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 3):

I see no one's answered this before. I assume you've already solved this, so this answer is for anyone else trying to find

The issue is that the `container` class has a fixed width of 960 pixels, so you can't nest them. The second problem is that the columns inside (that you're trying to nest) exceed the column count.  [See the 'clearfix' class](https://gist.github.com/dhg/959632). Offhand, this was the cleanest solution I found:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="four columns">four columns</div>
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="sixteen columns clearfix">                                                                                                                   
            <div class="three columns alpha"> first</div>
            <div class="three columns">second</div>
            <div class="three columns">third</div>
            <div class="three columns omega">fourth</div>
        </div><!-- end clearfix -->
    </div><!-- end twelve columns>
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The part that I missed the first time I saw this answer was that the columns in between Alpha and Omega are just labeled three columns. So for the first column use alpha and the last column use omega. The initial question doesn't work because they have two alpha and omegas. If you look at the css alpha and omega just give them 0px margins on either left(alpha) or right(omega).